# Multiple language LDAP attribute with JNDI

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ldap, jndi

I'm working on a Java project that interacts with Ldap via JNDI and while perusing I found some code that seemed a bit hackish.

There are some attributes that have multiple language values and in order to set those values there's some code along the way that does things like:

```
attributeName+ ";lang-" + language
```

Isn't there a better way to this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a pretty stale question at this point, but I am answering for the sake of posterity: What is being described is the way language codes are specified in LDAP, per [RFC 2596](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2596), based on "attribute options", specified in [RFC 4512 §2.5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4512#section-2.5.2).